# What is the best way forward when I see more than one good answer for my question?

Tags: discussion, questions, subjective

What is the best way forward when I see more than one good answer for my question? This happens a lot with open-ended questions, as I've seen with one of my earlier questions.

Comment: That's up to you.  Follow your instincts.  Just don't post any suggestions on how SO should change to better support that scenario because you'll get heavily down voted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume that the question is not *wildly* open-ended and simply *partially* open-ended. Such as 'My algorithm is XYZ, I need to improve it, any suggestions?'.

First, Chaos is correct, upvote all of them. Then mark as accepted the answer which is MOST helpful. Then, (in my case) I edited the question with a tag at the bottom that explained that both X and Y were incredibly useful responses, but I could only upvote one. This will typically point the question readers to read both posts, and upvote both of them if they like them.

Comment: +1 this is exactly what I try to do. I don't think it's always possible to ask questions that aren't open-ended to some degree, and so I do think this particular 'dilemma' is valid.

Answer (score 10):

Upvote them all and accept the best one.

And then go on to avoid asking open-ended questions in favor of questions with specific answers.

Answer (score 3):

But what to do with this open ended question? I could go ahead a post a good answer, but that would be just silly. Since chaos nailed it. :)

Answer (score 2):

I find with the bigger open-ended questions ("programmer cartoons", "defend PHP") that I simply read through dozens of answers anyway, the ones with most votes. An "accepted answer" is often meaningless in those cases.

So choose an answer if there is one, but otherwise just upvote and don't sweat it.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you have editing privileges, is to edit one answer such that it quotes, summarizes, cites, and links to the other. And then accept it. This way, you still have one comprehensive answer, but both authors get some credit.