# I edited my question to invite visitors to read all answers, the edit was removed, why?

Tags: discussion, review, edits

I have asked the following question on Travel StackExchange: [Is it offensive to use 'Saigon' instead of 'Ho Chi Minh City'?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85833/is-it-offensive-to-use-saigon-instead-of-ho-chi-minh-city)

Some questions have more than one good answer, regardless of whether they are open or not. I feel like this is the case here: I got quotes from books, people sharing their relatives' experience, people sharing their own experience... All these answers are valid, but as I can only accept one, I looked at the answers to that question in order to figure out what to do: [What is the best way forward when I see more than one good answer for my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/what-is-the-best-way-forward-when-i-see-more-than-one-good-answer-for-my-questio)

And so, I accepted the "best" answer, upvoted all the answers I liked, and edited the original question to thank people and invite visitors to not just stop at the accepted answer. However, [that edit was removed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/85833/revisions).

Could anyone explain me why?

Answer (score 8):

Questions should contain, well, the question. That's it. No fluff, no warm greetings, no further instructions about what to do with the answers. Just the question.

In a similar way answers should  just be answers. That keeps the information clean and is what distinguishes a Q&A from a forum.

So while you're definitely nice and appreciative, we just like to keep the sites clean the best we can. And that's why it will have been removed.

Comment: ... and the way to show appreciation for answers that helped you is to upvote and/or accept them.

Comment: I get that for the greetings and thankings. But there's definitely an undesirable side-effect to not encouraging visitors to read all answers. Sometimes one answer is enough, sometimes, it's not. I suppose the way cold pragmatism would solve that would be to have another answer compiling all the good bits of the other answers but that doesn't sound fair.

Comment: The other answers aren't hard to find and will have their own upvotes to indicate their quality. Don't worry about it too much.